# SSAS cube with date range records

Tags: sql-server, date, ssas

I have to build a cube based on date range records, and not sure about the best way to proceed.

Imagine say a cube of Cars and warranty periods.  Each car has a start date, and an end of warranty periods.   Then there may be extended warranty periods.. so imagine

```
CAR REG    TYPE      WARRANTY START    WARRANTY END
CAR A      PURCHASE    01/01/2016        31/01/2016
CAR A      EXTENDED    01/01/2017        30/06/2017
CAR A      EXTENDED    01/08/2017        30/01/2018  -- note, gap here
CAR B      PURCHASE    01/01/2016        31/01/2016
CAR B      EXTENDED    01/01/2017        30/06/2017
CAR B      EXTENDED    01/08/2017        30/01/2018  -- note, gap here
```

So multiple items, with multiple date ranges.   There is a main table (CARS) with car details (colour, model, etc).

Now I want to build a cube, which is reportable at month level, cars under warranty/warranty type, etc.

So plan 1 was to build a view which explodes the above out by a join to a date table, report by month, and feed this into a cube.  But, the number of cars multiplied by the months covered leads to multi hundreds of milions of rows - which means sometimes the server runs out of TempDB space, and when it does run, the cube takes hours to build.

Is there a better way - such as a view for the car details, and then another view on the warranty table (how do I get SSAS to deal with months in a date range) - will the join in SSAS be more efficient than a join in a view in SQL?

Thanks all.

Comment: Are you going to consume this cube with custom MDX queries or with a drag-and-drop tool like Excel?

Comment: Via Excel, Power BI and the like rather than MDX

Comment: how big is the data? About how many cars are there? It may influence my answer.

Comment: In terms of data, its bigish - the cars is about 750,000, covering about 6 years, with 12 months - so 750k rows x 6y x 12m = 54million possible combinations.   This is driven from 750k of car data, with a warranty table of some 1.9million rows to work out the warranty periods

Answer (score 1):

You can connect start and end columns to time dimension. And on the report you can use ":" operator to build date tange report.
More details you will find here: http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2013/04/mdx-between-start-date-and-end-date/

Answer (score 1):

One approach which will work with drag-and-drop client tools like Excel or Power BI would be a many-to-many Date dimension. Since car A and B match, let's pretend there's a car C which has a warranty from 2015-07-30 to 2015-12-31.

Create a DimWarrantyDateRangeKey which represents a unique combination of dates during which a warranty is active. The surrogate key is WarrantyDateRangeKey. Certainly the ETL that builds this table will be a bit expensive, but given the size of your data I think it's a worthwhile investment that will produce better query performance than if your m2m bridge table has one row per active day per car.

Each car should be assigned one WarrantyDateRangeKey. Add the WarrantyDateRangeKey column to your fact tables...

```
CAR REG   WarrantyDateRangeKey
A         1
B         1
C         2
```

m2mWarrantyDateRange

```
WarrantyDateRangeKey   DateKey
1                      20160101
1                      20160102
1                      ...
1                      20170629
1                      20170630
1                      20170801
1                      20170802
1                      ...
1                      20180129
1                      20180130
2                      20150701
2                      20150702
2                      ...
2                      20151230
2                      20151231
```

The tables relate together as follows...

`FactTable -> DimWarrantyDateRange <- m2mWarrantyDateRange -> DimDate`

Then in the cube you DimWarrantyDateRange should be a dimension, m2mWarrantyDateRange should be a measure group with a count measure. DimDate should be a dimension. Then you should relate DimDate to FactTable as a many-to-many (m2m) dimension using m2mWarrantyDateRange as the intermediate measure group.

Now in Excel or Power BI you should be able to filter to a particular date and it will filter down to the cars which had an active warranty on that day.

Comment: Would this set up still make sense if you had to consider default values (with DimWarrantyDateRange being 0, '1753-01-01', '9999-12-31')?

In this case, the limiting factor would be the min and max of your DimDate, but it would still be a lot of records. Would you still go with this solution for such cases?

Comment: @spikej I would assume you don’t have 8000 years in your date dimension. How long has your company been around? I would cap the m2m at the beginning and end of your date dimension. Luckily “all time” is just a single set of rows that all cars can use.